# converting a jQuery script in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, keyup

i need to understand how can i write this particular piece of jQuery code in the Backbone.js Version. This is the code that copies text or any input to some other div or field using the keyup() function.Since i am new to backbone i will be higly greatful if someone could sort this out

This is my index.html and the main.js code snippet

```
  <input type="text" name="Quantity" value="100"  id="quantity" />
```

```
$("#quantity").keyup(function () {
var value = $(this).val();
$("#quantity_img").text(value);}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`events` is a event map. `keyup #quantity` is a event `keyup` on object `#quantity`. `keyup` is a function handler defined above.

On `render` function fire `keyup` event.

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'keyup #quantity': 'keyup'
  },

  keyup: function() {
    var value = this.$('#quantity').val();
    this.$("#quantity_img").text(value);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$('#quantity').keyup();
  }
});
view = new View({el: $('#container')});
view.render();
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3z8sf113/1/

Comment: Thankyou so much sir!!..i can clearly get the concept from the fiddle..this was great help :) !